# How do I install lithium framework without git?

Tags: php, lithium

My webhost doesn't have git installed (I know, I know). I have downloaded the source code to the lithium project. How do I configure this to work on my webhost? I need the lithium core? Where does this go in relation to my `www` dir? I'm familiar with rails, if you could point out the analogues I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extract the source code in the webroot folder and follow the manual,

- [Installing Lithium](http://lithify.me/docs/manual/getting-started/installation.wiki).

Comment: I read that but I don't have git so I can't run `git submodule init`. This line "If you've downloaded the tarballs, make sure to unpack the core in the correct directory." I'm assuming that's the core dir. Where does this go in relation to my website root?

Comment: This https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/framework goes in the webroot folder and https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium goes in the libraries directory created in the first step. `git submodule` just do the second step using `git`. Hope that help.